# Mock SomeClass.getClassLoader() when called in method (Mockito / PowerMockito)

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have inherited some code that isn't tested and which loads a resource using a method like :

```
SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("somefile");
```

I've written the following test but there are 0 interactions with the Mock class loader I've created. Can anyone comment on whether this type of test is possible.

```
public enum SomeClass {

    INSTANCE;

    public boolean someMethod() {
        URL pathToLicense = SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("somefile"); 
        return false;
    }
}



@Test
public void testLicenseWorkflow(){

    ClassLoader cl = PowerMockito.mock(ClassLoader.class);

    File f = new File("someFile");

    assertTrue(f.exists());

    logger.info(f.getCanonicalPath()  ); 

    when(cl.getResource("somefile")).thenReturn(f.toURL());

    verify(cl).getResource("somefile");

    assertTrue(SomeClass.INSTANCE.someMethod());

}
```

**Update - Adding a resources via Classloader**
I've also tried the following but the someMethod this doens't seem to work either

```
new URLClassLoader(((URLClassLoader) SomeClass.INSTANCE.getClass().getClassLoader()).getURLs()) {
            @Override
            public void addURL(URL url) {
                super.addURL(url);
                logger.info("Calling add URL");
            }
        }.addURL(f.toURI().toURL());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `cl` to anything. You prepare a mock for a classloader but then proceed to load the resource with *another* classloader, the one that loaded `SomeClass`. That is why you have 0 interactions in your mock.

And about your first question, it is possible if somehow you pass your mocked classloader to the method that actually loads the resource. For example, something like

```
public boolean someMethod(Classloader loader) {
  URL pathToLicense = loader.getResource("somefile"); 
  return false;
}
```

But I have to say that IMO, this test is not very useful, you should be mocking your own components, not java classes. If your goal mocking the classloader is to inject a different file when testing, a better approach is to change your code to receive a Stream and inject a stream connected to the file in production and in testing inject a stream connected to an element in memory.

In other words, resources make for bad testing when they need to be changed at test time

Comment: Agreed about the code but I've inherited it and I don't have much scope to change it. I've also experimented with trying to add the new resource to the class loader but that hasn't seemed to work either. Thanks for your answer thuough

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? we know now that you can't modify `someMethod`, but why do you want to mock a classloader?